# Sidebar: Alignment issue after adding more than 2 items

Tags: css

Below, I have a rubric with two items (Portfolio and Contact)

(The preview is perfect)

[image]

I have a problem in my sidebar, when I add more than 2 items.

The preview is messed up :S

[image]

I would like to keep the same overview as before.

Sincerely, I don't understand where is the problem?

I share a reproduction via [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-fkdawy-bxleu5?file=src/styles.css), I think it will be easier.

I also share the CSS / HTML code below. I apologize for the length of the code.

Thank you in advance for your precious help.

***dashboard.component.html***

```
<ul class="nav-links" id="nav-links">
   <li
   *ngFor="let item of menuSidebar"
   [class.showMenu]="activeItem == item.link_name"
   #itemEl
   >
   <div
   *ngIf="item.sub_menu.length > 0"
   class="dropdown-title"
   (click)="showSubmenu(item)"
   >
   <a (click)="selectMenu(item)">
   <i [class]="item.icon"></i>
   <span class="link_name">{{ item.link_name }}</span>
   </a>
   <i class="bx bxs-chevron-down arrow"></i>
   </div>
   <ul class="sub-menu" [class.blank]="item.sub_menu.length == 0">
      <li>
         <a class="link_name">{{ item.link_name }}</a>
      </li>
      <li *ngFor="let item_sub of item.sub_menu" routerLinkActive="active">
         <a [routerLink]="[item_sub.link]">{{ item_sub.link_name }}</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

***styles.css***

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 260px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close {
  width: 60px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar .logo-details img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar .nav-links {
  height: 100%;
  width: 260px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar .nav-links::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links > li {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover {
  background: #eaeaea;
}

/* Dropdown Title */

.sidebar .nav-links .dropdown-title {
  width: 260px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.52s ease;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links .dropdown-title {
  width: 60px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li i {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #004a65;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover i,
.sidebar .nav-links li.active i {
  color: #004a65;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu i.arrow {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

/* a Tag */

.sidebar .nav-links li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Link Name */

.sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #004a65;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover a .link_name,
.sidebar .nav-links li.active a .link_name {
  color: #004a65;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li a .link_name {
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* Sub Menu */

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu {
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a {
  color: #004a65;
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  padding: 7px 0px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li:hover a,
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li.active a {
  color: red;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li:hover {
  background: #e8f5f9;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 5px 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li:last-child {
  padding: 5px 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu li {
  padding: 6px 15px;
  width: 200px;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu li:first-child {
  background: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu.blank {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu.blank,
.sidebar .nav-links li.active .sub-menu.blank {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close ~ .home-section {
  left: 60px;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .logo-details img {
  width: 37px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-3px);
}
```

Comment: Its clear you've copy pasted it. The CSS selectors select `:first-child` and `:nth-child(2)` This is probably the issue for you. I haven't reproduced this because I am not going to copy paste some template together to find out the issue with it. Please next time you post a question make sure it is a minimal reproduction of the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FUZIION mentioned you have to change this...

```
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 5px 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

...to this.

```
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li:not(:first-child) {
  padding: 5px 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

See the [forked](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-fkdawy-clddd9?file=src%2Fstyles.css) snippet.

Comment: thanks for your help. I understood the error now.